# About java Maps in eclipse

Tags: java

There is some open-source controller ([floodlight](https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight)) that I currently start understanding code structure but I saw this line in code is it right to add

```
Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<Long, Double>())
```

and what will be add to flowStatTable?

```
protected SortedMap <FlowEntry, SortedMap <Long, Double>> flowStatTable;
flowStatTable.put(matchedFlow, Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<Long, Double>()));
```

why accessed like this:

```
flowStatTable.get(matchedFlow).put(checkPointTimeStamp, utilization);
```

Comment: is this defining a tree map inside sorted map !!! im confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SortedMap <FlowEntry, SortedMap <Long, Double>>
```

This is declaring a `SortedMap`. The key type is `FlowEntry` and the value part is `SortedMap <Long, Double>` so another map with a `Long` key and a `Double` value.

```
flowStatTable.put(matchedFlow, Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<Long, Double>()));
```

This is adding a entry to the outer map. The key is `matchedFlow`, the value is

```
Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<Long, Double>())
```

This is taking a sorted map created with `new TreeMap<Long, Double>()` and using `Collections.synchronizedSortedMap` to converted it to a synchronized map to make it thread safe.

```
flowStatTable.get(matchedFlow).put(checkPointTimeStamp, utilization);
```

The first part of this `flowStatTable.get(matchedFlow)` is getting a value from the outer map, so the result of the get will be a `SortedMap <Long, Double>`. The `put(checkPointTimeStamp, utilization)` part is then storing a new key / value pair in this inner map.

You could write the code like this:

```
SortedMap<Long, Double> newInner = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<Long, Double>());

flowStatTable.put(matchedFlow, newInner);

...

SortedMap<Long, Double> existingInner = flowStatTable.get(matchedFlow);

existingInner.put(checkPointTimeStamp, utilization);
```

Comment: why the sequence in java is like that?? when we use this type of argument passing?

Comment: first we get flowStatTable.get(matchedFlow) then we put put(checkPointTimeStamp, utilization); in that key? am i right?

Comment: I have added the equivalent code using simpler steps to the answer.